# retrieving request.get variables in django/python

Tags: python, django

i have certain variables in my request.GET which are like 
product-21cad54c-fafe-11dd-9f2b-001b639ca120, product-11cvcfd1-fafe-11dd-9f2b-001b639ca120,
(the id is part of the variable name)

I want to store the id's of all these product variables, how can i retrieve these ids seperately?

Comment: if this is part of the url - use (r'^product-(?P<id>.+)', 'my_view'), then in views: def my_view(request, id):

Answer (score 4):

In your view, you can treat `request.GET` a bit like a `dict`. You can use:

```
request.GET.keys()
```

In the case of a url with the form: `http://foo/?bar=baz&bing=boom`, you would get `['bar','bing']`.

Is this what you are trying to do?

[After comment]

In that case, you should be able to:

```
for key in request.GET.keys():
    if key.startswith('product-'):
        the_id = key.split('-',0)[1]
        # Do some processing with the_id now…
```

Comment: The name of my keys are product-21cad54c-fafe-11dd-9f2b-001b639ca120, product-11cvcfd1-fafe-11dd-9f2b-001b639ca120, The product part is fixed while the id after the - changes. when i retrieving this request i want to be able to segregate the id part of these product variables and store them in a database.